# JavaScript редактирование JSON данных на сервере

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, post, xmlhttprequest

Задача: использовать ТОЛЬКО javascript (или ajax) для реализации сбора данных.

На сервере находится файл pickingdata.json (структура не имеет значения). Для получения данных используется функция readTextFile().

```
function readTextFile(file, callback) {
        var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
        rawFile.overrideMimeType("application/json");
        rawFile.open("GET", file, true);
        rawFile.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (rawFile.readyState === 4 && rawFile.status == "200") {
                callback(rawFile.responseText);
            }
        }
        rawFile.send(null);
    }
```

Данные успешно редактируются. Далее и возникает проблема. Если использовать ajax с php, то файл перезаписывается:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "savefile.php",
                    data: {'file':"pickingdata.json", 'data':datasend},
                    success: function(result){
                        if (result==1){
                            alert("Данные добавлены!");
                            window.location.href="index.html";
                        }
                        else {
                            alert("Ошибка на сервере! Обратитесь к администратору!");
                        }
                    }
                });
```

**НО по заданию использовать PHP НЕЛЬЗЯ!**
На просторах интернета нашла вариант использования XMLHttpRequest. Но метод POST не возвращает данные типа .json, а только File, txt и др.

```
var url  = "/example";
                    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                    xhr.open("POST", url, true);
                    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json; charset=utf-8');
                    xhr.onload = function () {
                        var users = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
                        if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == "201") {
                            console.table(users);
                        } else {
                            console.error(users);
                        }
                    }
                    xhr.send(datasend);
```

Возможно ли использование node.js для реализации данной задачи? Есть ли еще какие-либо варианты решения вышеописанной проблемы? HELP=(

Comment: Node.js определённо решит проблему в вашей интерпретации. Но сам запрет не использование PHP может реально быть запретом иметь серверную часть вообще: если задание дано не шибко прогрессивным преподавателем, который о Node.js не знает или только слышал краем уха. И в этом случае ваша интерпретация задания явно неправильная. Стоит прояснить этот момент с преподавателем.

Comment: Есть домен на платном хостинге, но он не поддерживает установку node.js. Поэтому придется реализовывать на xampp. Вопрос следующий: как работать в xampp с поддержкой node.js? Возможно, я некорректно задаю вопрос. Не работала никогда с node.js.

Comment: XAMPP вам может и не понадобиться. См. https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/getting-started-guide/ Но, ещё раз, я бы поставил под сомнение, верно ли вы интерпретировали задание. Чтобы не оказалось потом, что от вас хотели совсем не это.

Comment: Спасибо Вам большое! К сожалению, заказчик требует именно js-реализации поставленной задачи... Буду разбираться с node.js=(

Comment: А, т. е. у вас даже отношение заказчик-исполнитель, а не студент-преподаватель. Тем более стоит уточнить у заказчика, с чем связано требование сделать это без PHP. Если он ожидает, что это можно сделать без кода на сервере, его придётся разочаровать.

Comment: Просто Node.js, в сущности, прямая альтернатива PHP, просто использующая другой язык программирования. Если использовать PHP нельзя, наверняка использовать Node.js тоже нельзя.

Comment: Я уже поняла) по сути node.js нужен для написание сервера и реализации тех же функций, а использует он не js=) XMLHttpRequest нельзя использовать? перекопала кучу сайтов, туториалов, но нет ни одного примера записи именно json файла на сервер=(

Comment: У **любых** HTTP-клиентов нет прямого доступа для записи на сервер чего бы там ни было. На серверной стороне должна быть какая-то программа-обработчик, которая способна совершать запись сама. Реализована она на PHP, JS или Си -- вопрос десятый.

Comment: Если сервер поддерживает [WebDAV](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV), то можно *попробовать* обойтись и без PHP/Node.js.